# Mongodb and aggregation framework. Sum elements of arrays along to sum elements of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are many documents:

```
{
        "_id"   : ObjectId("506ddd1900a47d802702a904"),
        "subid" : "s1",
        "total" : "300",
        "details" :[{
                      name:"d1", value: "100"
                    },
                    {
                      name:"d2", value: "200"
                    }]
}
```

```
{
        "_id"   : ObjectId("306fff1900a47d802702567"),
        "subid" : "s1",
        "total" : "700",
        "details" : [{
                      name:"d1", value: "300"
                    },
                    {
                      name:"d8", value: "400"
                    }]
 }
```

Elements in 'details' arrays may vary.

Question is: how can I get such result with aggregation framework and java?

```
{
        "_id"     : "s1",
        "total"   : "1000",
        "details" : [{
                      name:"d1", value: "400"
                    },
                    {
                      name:"d2", value: "200"
                    },
                    {
                      name:"d8", value: "400"
                    }]
 }
```

Or maybe I should use custom map-reduce functions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very achievable with aggregate, though a little obtuse, but lets run through it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // First Group to get the *master* total for the documents
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$subid",
         "total": { "$sum": "$total" },
         details: { "$push": "$details" } 
     }},

     // Unwind the details
     {"$unwind": "$details"},

     // Unwind the details "again" since you *pushed* and array onto an array
     {"$unwind":"$details"},

     // Now sum up the values by each name (keeping levels)
     {"$group": {
         "_id:" {
              "_id": "$_id",
              "total": "$total",
              "name":  "$details.name"
          },
          "value": {"$sum": "$details.value"}
      }},

     // Sort the names (because you expect that!)
     {"$sort": { "_id.name": 1}},

     // Do some initial re-shaping for convenience
     {"$project": {
         "_id": "$_id._id",
         "total": "$_id.total",
         "details": { "name": "$_id.name", "value": "$value" }
     }},

     // Now push everything back into an array form
     {"$group": {
         "_id": {
              "_id": "$_id",
              "total": "$total"
         },
         "details": {"$push": "$details"}
     }},

     // And finally project nicely
     {"$project": {
         "_id": "$_id._id",
         "total": "$_id.total",
         "details": 1 
     }}
])
```

So if you *gave that a try* before, you might have missed the concept of doing the initial group to get the **top level** sum on your `total` field in your documents.

Admittedly, the **tricky** bit is *"getting your head around"* the whole *double unwind* thing that comes next. Since in that **first** group we pushed an *array* into another *array*, then we now end up with this new *nested* structure that you *need* to **unwind** *twice* in order to come to a "*de-normalized*" form.

Once you've done that, you just `$group` up to the `name` field:

> equiv (  GROUP BY _id, total, "details.name" )

So more or less like that with some sensible re-shaping. Then I ask to sort by the `name` key (because you printed it that way), and finally we `$project` into the actual form that you wanted.

So Bingo, we have your result. Thanks for the cool question to show the use of a **double unwind**.

Comment: Thank you for such fast answer, Neil! The real problem is the one document have many "total" fields and many various "details" arrays (7 actually), which contains 5-100 elements each. How many unwinds should I use in that case?:) May be should I change the document`s schema and extract those "details" arrays to separate collections?

Comment: @arctica That sounds pretty complex and is probably best represented in **another** question where you can be specific on the details. The approach is roughly the same, but I or someone else can better explain the construction if there is a question there with enough information so we can answer.